# How to put a particular image inside all images listed in a grid view?

Tags: android, xml, image, android-linearlayout, android-gridview

I am doing an android program using google api.I listed all images that are needed to be uploaded to the google drive inside a grid view.What i needed is that i needed to put a particular image on the top of all images that are  uploaded.For that first of all i need to put that particular image(a flower) on the top of all images that are listed.Can anyone suggest any method,it will be helpfull.
Advance thanks.....

This is my code to list all images inside a gridview.....

```
 public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    protected Cursor mCursor;
    protected int columnIndex;
    protected GridView mGridView;
    protected ImageAdapter mAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_photo_gallery);

        // Get all the images on phone

        String[] projection = {
                MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID,
                MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.IMAGE_ID
        };

        mCursor = getContentResolver().query(
                MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                projection,
                null,
                null,
                MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.IMAGE_ID + " DESC"
        );

        columnIndex = mCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(projection[0]);

     // Get the GridView layout
        mGridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView);
        mAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this);
        mGridView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }

    class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private Context mContext;

        public ImageAdapter(Context context) {
            mContext = context;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mCursor.getCount();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }

        // Convert DP to PX

        public int dpToPx(int dps) {
            final float scale = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
            int pixels = (int) (dps * scale + 0.5f);

            return pixels;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ImageView imageView;
            int imageID = 0;

            // Want the width/height of the items
            // to be 120dp
            int wPixel = dpToPx(120);
            int hPixel = dpToPx(120);

            // Move cursor to current position
            mCursor.moveToPosition(position);
            // Get the current value for the requested column
            imageID = mCursor.getInt(columnIndex);

            if (convertView == null) {
                // If convertView is null then inflate the appropriate layout file
                convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.conversation_item, null);
            }
            else {

            }

            imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

            // Set height and width constraints for the image view
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(wPixel, hPixel));

            // Set the content of the image based on the provided URI
            imageView.setImageURI(
                    Uri.withAppendedPath(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, "" + imageID)
            );

            // Image should be cropped towards the center
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);

            // Set Padding for images
            imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);

            // Crop the image to fit within its padding
            imageView.setCropToPadding(true);

            return convertView;
        }


    }


}
```

These are my xml files

activity_photo_gallery.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:columnWidth="100dp"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:gravity="center" />

</LinearLayout>
```

conversation_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Note:To put a particular image(for eg:a flower) on the top of all images that are listed inside the view is the thing that i needed.....any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use  a  frame layout to achieve this ...

conversation_item.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/FrameLayout1"
        android:layout_width="150dip"
        android:layout_height="150dip"
        android:layout_gravity="center" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/thumbImage"
            android:layout_width="150dip"
            android:layout_height="150dip"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="150dip"
            android:layout_height="150dip"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/select"
              />

    </FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Why negative vote!!Those who put negative votes please specify and correct the answer..

Answer (score -3):

Jack I think u need to redit ur activity_photo_gallery.xml file as :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:kuttichatan="error_pokatte"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: ohh mr Sasi i think you dont understand my question.anyway thanks

Comment: @sasi: Can you please explain  android:kuttichatan="error_pokatte"
from which SDK you are using this tag